# google repo project: how to restore accidentally removed git project?

Tags: git, repo

Say that if I have my project A organized with google [repo](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjXtcDD2eP4AhW1tlYBHYcjDG8QFnoECAMQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgerrit.googlesource.com%2Fgit-repo%2F&usg=AOvVaw0EPMo0xHMunL3IINmJTo_J), and this project have sub-project B and sub-project C

```
A(.repo)
|
--- B(.git)
|
___ C(.git)
```

If I deleted B accidentally, how to restore it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike normal git projects, `repo` store its metadata in the top-level `.repo` directory instead of the local `.git`. Even if you delete `B`, the meta-object(git objects) still exists in `.repo`, so your commits didn't get deleted in fact. Just `repo sync` to get your `B` back, and your local branchs/detached commits also go back. If you were working on the detached HEAD, use `git reflog` to find it.